# I want to display an array managed by Actor in UITableView

Tags: swift, actor

I have an actor like this

```swift
actor DataSource {
    var array = ["1"]
}
```

I would like to display this array in a table

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    dataSource.array.count
}
```

If you access it from within Task, an error will occur.
Is it not possible to display arrays managed by actors in a table?

Comment: It isn't possible. Why would you want to do that? You need your data model to be available on the main actor.

Comment: I want to display arrays accessed from multiple threads in a table
I want to display a table from the main actor, but I don't know how to do it.

thank you commented

Comment: You cannot use an actor, because actor's generally require _asynchronous_ access and the TableView, requires _synchronously_ returning a value in the delegate method running on the main thread (MainActor). As an alternative, you may use a class running on the MainActor, instead of an actor. UIKit is confined to the main thread, which is "somewhat" incompatible with actors.

Comment: Please add a comment on which language and platform this is, even if for an app developer it might be clear.